# Confusion regarding abcast function and uniqueness of gen_server names

Tags: erlang, message-passing, gen-server

From [erlang.org/doc](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#start_link-4), the gen_server section:

> start_link(ServerName, Module, Args, Options) -> Result
>
> If there already exists a process with the specified `ServerName` the function returns {error,{already_started,Pid}}

Apparently, Erlang does not allow multiple processes to have the same name.

Good, now let's look at [another function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#abcast-2):

> abcast(Name, Request) -> abcast
>
> Sends an asynchronous request to the *gen_servers* locally registered as `Name` at the specified nodes.

Notice the use of plural form.

Since Erlang requires unique name for gen_server processes, why would the `abcast` function implement async message sending to *multiple* processes that have the same name?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sends an asynchronous request to the gen_servers locally registered as Name **at the specified nodes**.

You can have several nodes with process registred as *Name*.

Comment: Yes, but `abcast/2` doesn't even accept the [Node] argument. So isn't `abcast` just `cast`?

Comment: `abcast/2` sends the message to all the nodes in the list `[node() | nodes()]`.

Comment: So `abcast/2` will send, by default, to all the active nodes in the corresponding VM?

Comment: Yes, `abcast/2` sends to all known nodes and to the sending node itself.